# Create animation of parametric plot

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric, maple

I would like to create an animation of parametric plot. With a moving point on curve. The parametric functions are:

> x(t) = (1/2)*exp(-(1/2)*t)*((160/11)*sin((1/2)*sqrt(11)*t)*sqrt(11)+20*cos((1/2)*sqrt(11)*t))
>
> y(t) = exp(-(1/2)*t)*(-(35/11)*sin((1/2)*sqrt(11)*t)*sqrt(11)+5*cos((1/2)*sqrt(11)*t))

Please help me, I am new in maple.

Answer (score 2):

Besides to @Robert's solution, I am giving you a small program in which you can find what you are looking for. I hope you can change it accordingly. This is my attempt:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice work...love the graph! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Hello Amy. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note: you are missing some * signs.

```
X:= [ (1/2)*exp(-(1/2)*t)*((160/11)*sin((1/2)*sqrt(11)*t)*sqrt(11)+20*cos((1/2)*sqrt(11)*t)),
    exp(-(1/2)*t)*(-(35/11)*sin((1/2)*sqrt(11)*t)*sqrt(11)+5*cos((1/2)*sqrt(11)*t))];
with(plots):
bg := plot([op(X),t=0..10]):
animate(pointplot,[X],t=0..10,colour=blue,symbol=solidcircle, symbolsize=20, background=bg);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition another answers;

[image]

Now click on the curve and play

[image]

Or right-click on the plot and play

[image]

Comment: $\color{green}{\large{+1}}$

Comment: $^+_++_+^+$ You need some more $\uparrow$s